# Mad as a hatter

Tags: riddle

> In the beginning I was as running Water  
>   Then I was only running - fast!  
>   (but the Water stayed - in my Title)  
>   Don't you want to go to school?  
>   Here, try and awake me in my glass Tower!  
>   Beware of my Cycle: unlike my simile,  
>   My clouds will not bring Life.

**What am I?**

---

<sub>The random capitalization has nothing to do with deciphering the riddle and everything to do with me having an Emily Dickinson attack. :D</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Mercury?

In the beginning I was as running water

> <strike>There is a water taxi company called mercury from BC (British Columbia).</strike> 
>  Mercury can be in liquid form.

Then I was only running - fast!

> <strike>The planet Mercury "runs" around the sun very fast.</strike>  Mercury is commonly known as "quicksilver" and quick means fast.

(but the Water stayed - in my Title)

> <strike>Wetting a hat(made of mercury) is a good way to break it in.</strike> It's name used to be "hydrargyrum" which means "water-silver".

Don't you want to go to school?

> If you got mercury poisoning you wouldn't be able to go to school.

Here, try and awake me in my glass Tower!

> Mercury used to be used in thermometers.

Beware of my Cycle: unlike my simile,

> There is a biogeochemical cycle called the mercury cycle and it has something to do chlorine factories https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_cycle

My clouds will not bring Life.

> Mercury can be deadly.

Relation to the title:

> Mercury is used in hats and makes the hatters go crazy.

Comment: You got it! But most lines are off: let's say that you're referring to two things with the same name, while I only refer to one.

Comment: Yay I got it! Well, sorta.

Comment: My spoiler aren't working

Comment: Updated to fix the spoilers (you can't have two different spoilers in a row like that I don't think, you need to use <br/> as a line break instead).

Comment: @El-Guest  Thanks I'll take note of that.

Comment: Way closer to what I meant! The explanation of the first line was meant to be the one you used for the third (because that one is its first name) whereas the third line refers to rot13(vgf purzvpny flzoby, Ut, npghnyyl orvat n fubeg sbez sbe ulqenetlehz). Fourth and fifth line were meant to stay together - but I like your drastic version better - and the fifth line simply referred to (ubcvat/cergraqvat gb unir srire gb fxvc fpubby ol urngvat n gurezbzrgre).

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Yes, I see that at first my reasons were… far off. :) Oh well, after some looking stuff up I found better reasons! Nice puzzle, btw.

Comment: Last two lines: rot13 (V jnf gelvat gb pbzcner gur plpyr bs jngre, juner jngre orpbzrf incbhe, jvgu zrephel incbhef, juvpu ner cbvfbabhf.) Your explanation worked way better, so  congrats!

Comment: @YoutRied thanks! It was my first riddle! If you have any feedback on strengths and weaknesses, I'd be glad to read them!

Comment: @LinuxBlanket I thought "A Horrible TV Show" was your first.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Here's some feed back: put enter between the clues of the answerers might not know they go together. Also, maybe you shouldn't randomly capitalize, as I read out what they said despite your note ("IIWTIWTDHTBCML" means nothing last time I checked)  Also, maybe find titles that people don't associate with the answer quickly. Other then that It was good! I liked it!

Comment: @YoutRied yes, but this one is the first in a more concise form. I didn't know how much the mad hatter thing was a giveaway, as in my native language is not known at all... should have hinted at it more subtly :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you (I already know I'm super far off with this, but what the heck)

> acid rain?

In the beginning I was as running Water

> At the beginning of the water cycle, the water runs along the ground.

Then I was only running - fast!

> When it evaporates, it's almost like running up into the sky to form clouds.

(but the Water stayed - in my Title)

> The water becomes "water vapour", so the word water stays in the title even though it's not liquid water.

Don't you want to go to school?

> Rain/acid rain/snow can sometimes cause school closures if it's truly, *truly* bad enough.

Here, try and awake me in my glass Tower!

> A tower in the sky, ie. a raincloud? Or maybe this refers to the smokestacks which give off atmospheric pollutants which cause acid rain.

Beware of my Cycle: unlike my simile,

> Acid rain becoming part of the water cycle is something to beware of.

My clouds will not bring Life.

> Don't stand in the acid rain, that's for sure.

Comment: Loved that response to *Don't you want to go to school?* in which rot13(npvq enva ZNL pybfr fpubbyf vs vg'f gehyl, gehyl, onq). :D Made me laugh.

Comment: @PerpetualJ thanks! That was me reminiscing about living in the only school district in my province that _never closed schools on snow days (or any other kind of days), haha!_ ;P

Comment: Haha! Same where I grew up, but you'd figure that rot13(vs gur ebbs jnf zrygvat) they would have bigger problems right? :)

Comment: If that starts happening, I agree you have much bigger problems than missing education for a day!! (Also, I just realized you changed your name!! That would've really given away one of your previous riddles!)

Comment: Yes, yes it would have; I felt the word *perpetual* is true to my nature. I've also noticed that most users typically don't include their full name as part of their usernames so I felt the change was appropriate.

Comment: Fun answer! :D not the one, though...